# Custom 'moment' pipe bug

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic2, momentjs, angular-pipe

I implemented the following custom pipe in my angular 2 app:

```
import { Injectable, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
  name: 'momentPipe'
})
@Injectable()
export class MomentPipe {
  transform(value: Date|moment.Moment, ...args: any[]): any {
    let [format] = args;
    return moment(value).format(format);
  }
}
```

It works well with 'standard' formats:

```
{{startDate | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
```

But when I try to print the day name:

```
{{startDate | date : 'ddd' }}
```

I get on the screen simply `ddd`. Just to be sure, in the `ts` file I do:

```
console.log(moment(this.startDate).format('ddd'));
```

and I get `Sat` for example.

I guess it has to do with compilation, but couldn't find neither good explanation nor a solution for it.

Comment: isn't it supposed to be `{{startDate | momentPipe : 'ddd' }}`?

Comment: There's already a date pipe in Angular 2, are you sure you aren't accidentally using that? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the built in Angular2 date pipe, `date` instead of your `momentPipe`, `| moment:`

However, you should still be able to do this with [`date`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html)

```
{{startDate | date: 'EEE'}}
```

Comment: If you are not using `momentPipe` for anything else, remove the library and use the native Angular2 date pipe as suggested here!